# Is there a way to read a parquet file from an InputStream in Java?

Tags: java, amazon-s3, bigdata, parquet

I am trying to read a parquet record from S3, S3 usually returns an input stream, which I want to retrieve the data from. Am using java , and I don't want to use spark's built in reader. is there a way to do this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not parse a Parquet file from an InputStream because [internally parquet-mr](https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr/blob/master/parquet-common/src/main/java/org/apache/parquet/io/SeekableInputStream.java) seeks through the file.

For example file meta information about the schema is persisted at the end of the file and the first thing that parquet does is to go to the end of file.

One option is to download completely the file, and then parse it.